# How do I authorize a Windows Phone 7 device to allow for visual studio to deploy to it?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-phone-7, zune

I've registered as an app developer with the Microsoft store but I'm at a loss, under devices I'm told that I need to authorize devices to use for app development but it says: "Adding additional devices must be accomplished through Visual Studio" with no added information. I tried using the 'XNA Game Studio Device Center' to add the device but it only has Zune and Xbox 360 listed, clicking on Zune doesn't help as it says no Zune device was found (since it's a windows phone 7 device I suppose that's to be expected).

So how do I add a device so I can deploy to it through visual studio?

Comment: Oh how I know that one - it never occured to me to look for a start menu entry to register my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the live id for your active marketplace subscription, enter that and your password into Windows Phone Developer Registration in the start menu.

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks. Just one small correction, the program to run is 'windows phone developer registration', in case someone does a search for windows phone device registration and finds nothing. I'm having a different problem (error code: 0x80043009) but that doesn't seem relevant to this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yea, didnt check as I wrote. Updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can only register a device using windows phone developer registration program once you have completed GEO Trust verification.  On your Windows Phone dash board on App Hub you'll see that you must complete verification before your able to register a device.